# Change Flash variable using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, flash

I am running an swf `preview.swf`, How can i change the value of flash variable `mode` using jquery ??

I have code something like

`AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "preview",
            "width", "378",
            "height", "550",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "preview",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF",
            "name", "monogram_preview",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "FlashVars", "mode=0",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's Function.apply() method:

```
var parameters = ["src", "preview", "width", "378", "height", "550", "align",
    "middle", "id", "preview", "quality", "high", "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF", "name",
    "monogram_preview", "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain", "type", 
    "application/x-shockwave-flash", "FlashVars", "mode=0", "pluginspage", 
    "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"];
parameters[21] = 'foo'; // Flashvar change.
AC_FL_RunContent.apply({}, parameters);
```

That being said, consider utilize SWFObject or some other modern way of embedding Flash.